# JSON Array output Android App Development

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to output the information from a JSON array onto my Android Application however, it doesn't seem to output when i run it through a for loop.

The JSON array code outputs as is before hand once the button has been hit but after implementing the for loop to output specific information, all i get is blank.

Comment: what do you think this `parentObject.getJSONArray("")` does?

Comment: @njzk2 the array doesn't have a name so i left it blank

Comment: @MoAlamin Post your json data you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your JSON root element is `array` not `object` this code will not work:

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("");
```

First it will fail to create object (because you got array), and second, you cannot lookup for element with empty index (you should have checked your logcat for stacktrace as this shall end throwing exceptions).

Instead of the above, you should just create array directly:

```
JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(finalJson);
```